When using WC_Product_Variable, it creates a simple product
I am trying to progmatticly create a Variable Product in WooCommerce like so:
           $currentProduct = new WC_Product_Variable();

    
    
    $currentProduct->set_name( $product['Title'] );
    $currentProduct->set_sku( time() );
    $currentProduct->set_stock_quantity( -1 );
    $currentProduct->set_description($product['Body (HTML)'] );


    $imageId = download_image($product['Image Src']);

    $currentProduct->set_image_id( $imageId );
    $currentProduct->set_regular_price( 500.00 );

    $category_ids = [$categories[$product['Type']]];
    var_dump($category_ids);

    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        array_push($category_ids , $categories[trim($tag)]);
    }

    $currentProduct->set_category_ids( $category_ids );
    $currentProduct->save();

            $variation = new WC_Product_Variation();

    $variation->set_parent_id( $currentProduct->get_id() );

    $variation->set_attributes( array( 'type' => $product['Option1 Value'] ) );
    $variation->set_regular_price( $product['Variant Price'] );
    $variation->save();

However the created Product is a simple product and not a variable product.  Has any got any idea why this is?
The questions mine have been assioated with do not answer my question.   This is how it is stated in the documentation.  There must be another reason why it is not working.  The other questions show methods that are not correctly done. This is the correct way to create a variable product.
I wrote code which looks like it should create a Variable Product.

Hi, I am sorry but my question is not a duplicate.  The code is correct, there must be a reason why it is not working?
